# Need to make a stock inventory application

Tags: java, web-applications, mysql, web-services, tomcat

I need to make an application for my dad to keep track of stock trading inventory. He trades shares for himself and for his clients and would like to keep the records, things like buy/sell price of shares, profits, loss, date etc etc for his shares and his client shares and would like various kind of reports/views.

He uses windows. I want to provide a local html page where he will enter new information and this should go to a local database and from his html page, he can choose reports etc and the reports will be displayed on the webpage etc..

I am thinking of using struts (and windows,tomcat) and mysql to make this application. I know some stuff from college days, but would look into the tutorials to setup things and program.

Does this selection of technology looks good enough or something more easier and equally good exist?

**update:**

This is what I have settled for: Used mysql/windows, navicat lite and populated database/tables, and wrote some procedures taking some inputs. Like one procedure takes date and stock name as input and gives you quantity you have of that stock by that date and profit/loss so far, effective buy price of each share of that stock. This is for individual basis usage..and it looks like this will suffice for now -- very very simple, but I could custom create tables,custom create queries/procedures..Dad gets "contract notes" from his broker containing his daily transactions and I could get these notes online, compile these of last 2-3 years into one table and so the thing is in working state..very primitive, but works for his requirements for now.
and yes, made 2 accounts (one read-only priviledge account using which he will run his queries,procedures etc) and other root, which he will use when populating his tables say once or twice in 15 days.

Comment: I work on a trading system. There are about 30 of us and we (not necessarily me) have been doing it for 10+ years. It still sucks. I am not saying that you need all that functionality, but it can get very complex very fast. There are many people out there who wish to compete with Facebook without realizing that FB has 1000+ smart employees. Not that it cannot be beaten, but it will take a group of very smart people. As someone else suggested, your father is better off buying something that is good.

Comment: Are there other users? Seems like a desktop app and database would be easier.

Comment: This is going to be a very very simple application - single user and not needing network. This is what I have settled for: Used mysql/windows, navicat lite and populated database/tables, and wrote some procedures taking some inputs. Like one procedure takes date and stock name as input and gives you quantity you have of that stock by that date and profit/loss so far, effective buy price of each share of that stock. This is for individual basis usage..and it looks like this will suffice for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) with Java and MySQL for this. It's a typical database oriented application, so you should design the database schema carefulle before you start coding. Play Framework is a Java web framework with a short development cycle, just save your source code and update your web page - inpired by Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that there are off-the-shelf applications that already do this.  Personally, I'd rather spend some cash to get something that I know has been thoroughly tested than spend hours and hours developing one myself.

Comment: 1) there are any number of reasons why the OP desires to roll his/her own - these are not explained and assumptions should be kept to a minimum; 2) is it cheaper to have a relative provide you with a custom piece of software or purchasing the software? ;) Not to mention, software support is going to be cheaper and much more reliable!

Comment: @IAbstract - totally disagree with you. I've never built a house, but could build one for you a lot cheaper. Enjoy your new shack. Here father has a business and should be working with his clients instead of having someone reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Jeff: not quite the same, IMHO. In this case, the OP **is** a software developer asking for recommendations for what tools to use to develop a piece of software. Comparing the OPs objective to someone building a house with no structural experience is invalid. That said, I do not disagree with the suggestion that there are applications already available and bestattendance makes a good recommendation. But it does not answer the OP's question, either. :)

Comment: Since this does not answer the OPs question, it should be a comment. Note, I agree with the **comment**.